# pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Was not found appropriate resource to download for request

Tags: java, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pycharm, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I'm trying to run the example code below:

```
import sparknlp
sparknlp.start()

from sparknlp.pretrained import PretrainedPipeline

explain_document_pipeline = PretrainedPipeline("explain_document_ml")
annotations = explain_document_pipeline.annotate("We are very happy about SparkNLP")
print(annotations)
```

I'm using Pycharm in Anaconda env, originally I downloaded spark-nlp with `pip spark-nlp==2.4.4` but I saw someone online said I should use:

```
pyspark --packages com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp_2.11:2.4.4
```

Because with `pip` install I might have some dependencies missing, so better use `pyspark --packages`, but this gave me error:

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                [NOT FOUND  ] com.typesafe#config;1.3.0!config.jar(bundle) (0ms)

        ==== local-m2-cache: tried

          file:/C:/Users/xxxxxxxx/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/config/1.3.0/config-1.3.0.jar

                [NOT FOUND  ] com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.6.0!jackson-annotations.jar(bundle) (0ms)

        ==== local-m2-cache: tried

          file:/C:/Users/xxxxxxx/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.0/jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

                :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: com.typesafe#config;1.3.0!config.jar(bundle)

                :: com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.6.0!jackson-annotations.jar(bundle)

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
        unknown resolver null

        unknown resolver null

        unknown resolver null

        unknown resolver null

        unknown resolver default

        unknown resolver null


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [download failed: com.typesafe#config;1.3.0!config.jar(bundle), download failed: com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.6.0!jackson-annotations.jar(
bundle)]
```

Then I downloaded these two missing jars and copy them to the corresponding folder, then run the command and everything seems look fine now:

```
21/02/05 15:41:13 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.4
      /_/

Using Python version 3.7.1 (default, Oct 28 2018 08:39:03)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>>
```

Then I tried to re-run the example python script at the top, it gave me error, here's the logs:

```
Ivy Default Cache set to: C:\Users\xxxx\.ivy2\cache
The jars for the packages stored in: C:\Users\xxxx\.ivy2\jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/workEnv-python3.7/lib/site-packages/pyspark/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
com.johnsnowlabs.nlp#spark-nlp_2.11 added as a dependency
............
```

I'm new to this, I've been messing around for two days, might someone able to help me please???

Comment: It seems it can't download some dependencies. Try using the fat [jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/johnsnowlabs/nlp/spark-nlp_2.11/2.4.4/spark-nlp_2.11-2.4.4.jar) : `pyspark --jar spark-nlp_2.11-2.4.4.jar`

Comment: Hi I'm able to download with `pyspark --jar spark-nlp_2.11-2.4.4.jar` but turns out my project needs spark-nlp 2.5.4, when I try `pyspark --jar spark-nlp_2.11-2.5.4.jar` it's still installing 2.4.4, should I uninstall 2.4.4jar first? and how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Oh dear, I just did `pip install spark-nlp==2.5.4` then run the script again, everything is ok now! This bloody stupid mistake..... Thanks @blackbishop